# Stop display through object despite transparent material?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, shader, renderer

This is very difficult to describe, but I feel like it should be possible to do.

Essentially, this is where I am at:

[image]

Since the Earth's material has outer normals, its own material is not displayed on the other side of the globe.  However, due to the transparency of the material, I see the markers that exist on the other side of the globe.

How can I stop things from displaying through the material?  The background is the skybox and is the only thing that I would like to show through the transparency.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: you mean the green skyscrapers right ?  indeed, you will be able to see the ones on the far side...

Comment: Just sort of a pointer for anyone googling here. In some cases sort of like this you need `TransparencySortMode.Orthographic` to solve the problems of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a little tricky to do this:

the only way is:

turn OFF each green skyscraper, when, it is at the "back".

Let's say your world is simply centered on 000.

In that case, if you think about it it is this simple...

If `z>0f`, then you want the green skyscraper to be invisible.  If it is `z<0f` you want it to appear normally.

Since this is Unity you must work in an agent-like manner.  So actually it's this simple.  Make a script (pseudocode)

```
Class HideMeIfAwayFromCamera
{
Update()
 {
 if ( z > 0f ) renderer.enabled = true;
 else renderer.enabled = false;
 }
}
```

That's probably your simplest and best solution here.  in any event, I would try that first. Let's hear how it works for you.

Consider that you may want to make the on/off point a little ahead or behind the half-way plane, try it.

Note that another approach is. You kind of need to use a cutout shader; use a different layer altogether for the skyscrapers; and use yet another layer for any skyscrapers who's base is beyond the horizon; in this way you can let it show the "tops" of any skyscrapers that are "just behind" the horizon but hide the bases. It does seem way too complicated though. I think the best result will be just turning off the rear ones, as shown above.

(Note too that it's not "physical".  If the globe is transparent: you SHOULD be able to see the skyscrapers at the back. So you'd have to try some things to see what feels good.)

Comment: I thought about this method, but I stopped and decided to ask here first.  My biggest concern is with the number of them.  There are roughly 1000.  Would something like this be intensive to run in Update?

Comment: No no.  Thank you for reaffirming this solution.  I just tried it and it worked well.  But I am curious about the other method of shaders.  Do you have any reference for a "cutout shader" that I could look at as an alternative.

Comment: Marked as answer either way.

Comment: unity's own doco is fair, you could start there .. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-TransparentCutoutFamily.html  It's definitely a real chore getting in to shaders, you know.  it's an effort!

Comment: you can use the dot product to easily tell facing and its only multiplications. i have not looked into shaders yet, but im quite sure dot is available. but it would just work in the above way, the advantage is that it would be independent from view or world position.

Comment: Joe, you asked to let me know how it worked out for me.  And while it seems like there's certainly some added overhead in the profiler in BehaviorUpdate, I'm still at a very good framerate.  This is a tiny screen shot of how the method worked for me:  http://i.imgur.com/PoYucsE.png 

Thank you for continuing to answer my questions!

Comment: great news. I'm surprised to hear it added much overhead so thanks for reporting that.  Cheers! thanks again